# how can I assign my dataset cells to appropriate datagridview cells which has the coulmns I added?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` in my windows form with 5 columns I added.

```
Item Code | Description | Quantity | Rate | Item Total
```

These are the headers of the columns I have in my data grid view.

I am retrieving data from database to a dataset using the following procedure.

```
create proc [dbo].[get_an_invoice_details]
    @inv_no int
as
    select 
        inv_item_code, inv_item_desc, inv_item_qty, inv_item_rate, 
        (inv_item_qty * inv_item_rate) item_total
    from 
        invoice 
    where 
        inv_no = @inv_no;
GO
```

Now I want show this item code in the data gridview column named Item Code. Same as for other columns respectively. But when I give the dataset variable as data source it won't show like that. Data is showing. But not in this columns. 5 new columns are generating and these ones are blank in grid view. please see the screen shot. And I made auto generate column property to false. But then nothing shows.

This is the code for the retrieve button:

```
private void btn_retrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtgrdvw_items.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    string sql = "get_an_invoice_details @inv_No=" + Convert.ToInt32(txt_inv_no.Text) + ";";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    con.Open();
    da.Fill(ds, "invoice");
    con.Close();

    dtgrdvw_items.DataSource = ds;
    dtgrdvw_items.DataMember = "invoice";
}
```

Application screenshot after retrieval

[image]

Comment: include DataPropertyName for datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `DataPropertyName` for `DataGridView` as shown in below code. you should be good.

```
 private void btn_retrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dtgrdvw_items.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dtgrdvw_items.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "inv_item_code";
            dtgrdvw_items.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "inv_item_desc";
            dtgrdvw_items.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "inv_item_qty"; 
            dtgrdvw_items.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "inv_item_rate"; 
            dtgrdvw_items.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "inv_item_total";
            string sql = "get_an_invoice_details @inv_No=" + 
            Convert.ToInt32(txt_inv_no.Text) + ";";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds, "invoice");
            con.Close();
            dtgrdvw_items.DataSource = ds;
            dtgrdvw_items.DataMember = "invoice";

        }
```

Comment: @SijoGeorgeOommen Im glad that i was able to help you . pls accept answer!

Answer (score 0):

dtgrdvw_items.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Item Code";